# Karma unit test cross domain resource AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, karma-runner

I use karma as my angular project test running framework, my angular have server service need to access another web url to get data like `http://localhost:8081/common/countries` get all information about country.
my problem is my karma start at `localhost:9876` and it need to get data from `http://localhost:8081/common/countries` this cause cross domain problem by the browse same-origin policy. 
so I get below error in my console:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:8081/common/countries
No more request expected
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at $httpBackend (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/WebUI/WebUI/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:934:9)
    at sendReq (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/WebUI/WebUI/vendor/angular/angular.js:9087:9)
    at $http (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/WebUI/WebUI/vendor/angular/angular.js:8878:17)
    at Object.getMock (http://localhost:9876/base/share/services.js:644:17)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/base/share/services.js:347:28)
    at Object.getCountries (http://localhost:9876/base/share/services.js:221:22)
    at Object.clSingleSelectConfig.nationality.getData (http://localhost:9876/base/share/directives.js:146:32)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/share/directives.js:192:44
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/WebUI/WebUI/vendor/angular/angular.js:4360:13)
```

What i have tried:
1 install karma plugin karma-chrome-launcher and add `--disable-web-security` in my config file. but it doesn't work.
2 set'Access-Control-Allow-Origin''Access-Control-Allow-Headers''Access-Control-Allow-Methods' in header to allow origin access in server response.

all above don't work, so how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cross domain requests use [**expectJSONP**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend#methods_expectjsonp) and be sure to use a callback parameter.

```
describe('stackoverflow.activity tests', function () {
    var svc, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function (){  
      module('ngResource');
      module('stackoverflow.activity');
      inject(function($httpBackend, StackoverflowActivityService) {
        svc = StackoverflowActivityService;      
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
      });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should send the message and return the response', function (){
        var returnData = { testing: 'anything'};
        httpBackend.expectJSONP('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/gigablox/timeline?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').respond(returnData);
        svc.events({
            user:'gigablox',
            params:{
                callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        }).get(function(user) {
            expect(user.testing).toEqual('anything');
        });
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

[**Source for this example**](https://github.com/gigablox/angular-stackoverflow-activity/blob/master/src/test/stackoverflow-activity.test.js)